# Adding a loading image on Upload button click is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, loader

I want a functionality where, whenever a user is uploading a file by clicking on the button. Untill the data keeps loading in the background, I want is a loader to be showed in the form.

So for that I added a `div`  like below

```
<div id="divLoadingPanel" class="Loadingdiv">
    <img src="Images/loading.gif" alt="loading" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function showLoadingPanel() {
        $("#divLoadingPanel").show();
    }
```

So on button click, I am calling it like below from server side

```
protected void btnUploadExcelData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "loadImage", "showLoadingPanel()", true);
        UploadValidateExcelFile();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {            
        throw;
    }
}
```

But I am unable to see the loader whenever I click the button.
Please suggest why its not working,

**NOTE**: The same loader is working when I use it on `onchange` of dropdownlist.

Comment: how do you do the background loading?

Comment: @madalinivascu: I just show an `image` loading in the background by displaying it on `onchange`. ex:- `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="STATENAME"
                        onchange="showLoadingPanel();" DataValueField="STATECODE" AutoPostBack="True"
                        CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>` here is works, but not on server side

Answer (score 0):

Pay more attention to separate client-side code with server-side one. When you use **server-side Click event**, then a postback will occur. It means that your client side code will be registered to be don after postback response received by client. So in a duration from sending request to server and getting response, no action will be done. Why it works using `onchange` in your dropdown? Because you are using **client-side event** not server side one! Your solution is using ajax code to send and receive data asynchronously without any postback (page refreshing) and use some javascript code to show a load-image until server responses. Second way you can use if you are not familiar with ajax is using .Net ajax controls like UpdatePanel.

**JQuery Exapmle:**

```
function sendData(dataValue)
{
    $("#divLoadingPanel").show();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Your_Page/Your_Method",
            data: dataValue,                
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("We returned: " + result);
            },
            complete: function(){
                $("#divLoadingPanel").hide();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: ok, got it. but with some example and code would be great for me.

Comment: are you familiar with jQuery? or raw javascript code you need?

Comment: i m not much familiar with jquery, it would be great if you share the js code

Comment: But you are using jQuery in your code. I edited my answer to give you jQuery example because it's very simple than raw js. if you want js version, you can visit [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).